# how to display news in a static block in home page

Tags: magento

what is the best free extension to show news scrolling on MAGENTO homepage. I have googled a lot but did not found any news or blog new extension

Comment: i need an extension which will show scrolling headlines of news in my homepage

Answer (score 0):

There is free extension available for that you can use any one of them

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/news-5.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/news.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/medma-news.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/news-extension-1.html